# “This video is unavailable” - html with iframe for WKWebView embedding

Tags: swift, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I need to embed Youtube video using iframe. According to a test project when I try using youtube_ios_player_helper with function

```
-(BOOL)loadWithVideoId:(nonnull NSString *)videoId playerVars: (nullable NSDictionary *)playerVars

let vars = ["origin": "http://www.youtube.com"]
playerView.load(withVideoId: "gqbB8-sBuvg", playerVars: vars)
```

the video is working. If I don't use additional parameters, I see: `"This video is unavailable"`. But for iframe, I only see `"This video is unavailable"`. I'm using the following html:

```
videoWebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(videoWebView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(videoWebView.frame.height)\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/gqbB8-sBuvg?enablejsapi=1&origin=\"http://www.youtube.com\"\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

How to fix the iframe embedding?

Comment: The [Embed YouTube Videos in iOS Applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) with the YouTube Helper Library suggests that you can use the youtube-ios-player-helper. It's an open source library that helps you embed a YouTube iframe player into an iOS application. The library creates a UIWebView and a bridge between your application’s Objective-C code and the YouTube player’s JavaScript code, thereby allowing the iOS application to control the YouTube player.

Comment: @noogui Got it. But I need only html-string for loading a video with a correct body in my case. Is there an opportunity not to use the YouTube Helper Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem with iframe embedding you don't need to use the **YouTube Helper Library**.
The problem was with **baseURL**. Instead of receiving nil, there needs to be a link or a path for resources.

For example,

```
videoWebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe>...</iframe>", baseURL: URL(string: "http://www.youtube.com")!)
```